# mousedown event handler on table rows in different browsers

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

I want to be able to select a row from a table by registering a mousedown event on each row of a named table (see code). I'm testing in Firefox 14.0, Chrome 20.0.1132.47, and IE 8 (for testing).

In the event handler I write the type of element (tag name) to the console, expecting it to be `TR` each time. This works as expected in Firefox, but Chrome and IE return `TD`, even though the handler is registered on the `TR`.

```
<script>
var myFuncs = {
   // generic stop event bubbling up any further (DOM level2 and IE)   
   stopProp: function (event){
      if (!event) var event = window.event;
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
   },
   // generic add event listener   
   addListener : function(elt,evt,listener){
      if (document.attachEvent){
         elt.attachEvent ("on"+evt,listener);
      }
      else {
         elt.addEventListener (evt,listener,false);
      }
   },
   // the function that is supposed to handle mousedown events on <tr> tags
   handleMousedown : function(evt) {
      myFuncs.stopProp(evt);
      elt = (window.event) ? window.event.srcElement : evt.currentTarget;
      console.log(elt.tagName);
   },
   // attach/add event listener to <tr> elements in named table
   registerEvts : function(){
      var tab = document.getElementById("dataGrid");
      var rows = tab.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (var ix=0; ix < rows.length; ix++){
         myFuncs.addListener (rows[ix],"mousedown",myFuncs.handleMousedown);
      }
   }
}

window.onload = myFuncs.registerEvts;
</script>
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem? It causes problems as I'd subsequently have to test to see if it was the row or the cell I was dealing with.

Comment: I've used jquery.on which does a great job of normalizing the behavior.  Additionally, it actually registers the event handler at the table (or document) level, then matches the event based on CSS selectors, so you have only 1 event function.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I may go down the jquery route, but for the moment I'm trying to understand the difference in behaviour between the browsers. Is this non-standard behaviour in IE and Chrome, or is my code not specific enough?

Comment: By playing abour a bit more wuth the code I've discovered that Chrome actually emulates both DOM 2 and IE event model,i.e it defines a document.attachEvent as well as a addEventListner. So my test in myFuncs.addListener was forcing Chrome to act like IE.

Comment: I'm having similar problems, and think it's really sad when all the solutions seem to require jquery...